# Encrypt/Decrypt Password in Oracle Function

Tags: oracle, encryption, plsql

Due to previously poorly designed structure, the current database that I have to work with stores users' password as text.

Now, I am building a front end part that has to use those passwords and I certainly don't want to be sending passwords unencrypted.

My idea is to write an Oracle function to encrypt and decrypt text password and use those functions in the stored procedures that will return encrypted data.

What would be the best approach in Oracle to do so?

Comment: Nobody's mentioned it in the answers (yet), but you should *never* decrypt passwords.  Instead, you should *encrypt* what the user entered and compare that to the encrypted password. Most (good) password schemes use a one-way cryptographic hash, so they **can't** be decrypted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to write your own functions to encrypt and decrypt data, you would simply want to call the [DBMS_CRYPTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#i1001225) `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods with appropriate parameters (i.e. pick your encryption algorithm, your key, etc.).

Of course, if you write your own routines, assuming that you store the key in the database or somewhere the database has access to, you're not doing much for security.  It's bad to send passwords unencrypted over the network but it is generally much worse to store unencrypted passwords in the database (or encrypted passwords if there is a `decrypt` method in the database that has access to the key to decrypt the data).  It's generally a lot easier to steal data from a database than it is to sniff data getting sent over the network in order to find a password.

The right answer, of course, would be to rearchitect the system so that you don't store the passwords at all.  You should be storing password hashes (which you can also generate using the `DBMS_CRYPTO` package) which are non-reversible.

Comment: I certainly agree with you, but at this point it seems that the database will not be rearchitected.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at DBMS_CRYPTO

It has methods to encrypt and decrypt data built in.  Better than writing your own.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use the password hashing algorithm pbkdf2 like this http://mikepargeter.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/pbkdf2-in-oracle/
I verified the outcome with the rfc https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt and it works fine.

Check this link for minimal iterations and key_size: [PBKDF2 recommended key size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943837/pbkdf2-recommended-key-size)
Note that the result is double the length, because it is hex-encoded.

we store these columns in the db

```
PASSWORD_HASH                 VARCHAR2(512 BYTE),
PASSWORD_SALT                 VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
PASSWORD_ITERATIONS           NUMBER(10),
PASSWORD_HASH_METHOD          VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
PASSWORD_CHANGED_DT           DATE
```

the hash, salt and iterations are to feed the pbkdf2 algorithm
the hash_method is for migration purposes
and the changed_dt is to expire passwords

Answer (score 3):

Here's a packaged function (successful implementation) for encrypting passwords using (`DBMS_CRYPTO`)-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY encrypt_paswd
AS
  G_CHARACTER_SET VARCHAR2(10) := 'AL32UTF8';
  G_STRING VARCHAR2(32) := '12345678901234567890123456789012';
  G_KEY RAW(250) := utl_i18n.string_to_raw
                      ( data => G_STRING,
                        dst_charset => G_CHARACTER_SET );
  G_ENCRYPTION_TYPE PLS_INTEGER := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256 
                                    + dbms_crypto.chain_cbc 
                                    + dbms_crypto.pad_pkcs5;
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --Encrypt a password 
  --Salt the password
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  FUNCTION encrypt_val( p_val IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN RAW
  IS
    l_val RAW(32) := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW( p_val, G_CHARACTER_SET );
    l_encrypted RAW(32);
  BEGIN
    l_val := utl_i18n.string_to_raw
              ( data => p_val,
                dst_charset => G_CHARACTER_SET );

    l_encrypted := dbms_crypto.encrypt
                   ( src => l_val,
                     typ => G_ENCRYPTION_TYPE,
                     key => G_KEY );

    RETURN l_encrypted;
  END encrypt_val;
END encrypt_paswd;
```

This uses `encrypt_aes256` -"Advanced Encryption Standard. Block cipher. Uses 256-bit key size." , `chain_cbc`- "Cipher Block Chaining. Plaintext is XORed with the previous ciphertext block before it is encrypted." and `pad_pkcs5` - "Provides padding which complies with the PKCS #5: Password-Based Cryptography Standard".

In addition to this You can create a similar function to decrypt. like -

```
  FUNCTION decrypt_val( p_val IN RAW ) RETURN VARCHAR2  
  IS
    l_decrypted RAW(32);
    l_decrypted_string VARCHAR2(32);
    l_user  VARCHAR2(32);
  BEGIN
    SELECT user 
      INTO l_user
      FROM dual;

    if l_user = 'ADMIN' -- you can restrict usage of decrypt to certain db users only.
    then
        l_decrypted := dbms_crypto.decrypt
                ( src => p_val,
                  typ => G_ENCRYPTION_TYPE,
                  key => G_KEY );

        l_decrypted_string := utl_i18n.raw_to_char
                    ( data => l_decrypted,
                      src_charset => G_CHARACTER_SET );
        RETURN l_decrypted_string;
    else            
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'You are not authorized to use this function - decrypt_val()');
    end if;
    RETURN 'Unknown';
  END decrypt_val;
```

You may also consider wrapping the package before compiling it in the database using `wrap iname=package_name.pkb` and then compiling the resulting `plb`.

Comment: can this be implemented for clobs

Answer (score 1):

user this code definitely work

```
create or replace PACKAGE          "PKG_LOGI_PWD_REG" 
AS
  function ENCRYPT_VAL( P_VAL in varchar2 ) return varchar2;
  function DECRYPT_VAL( P_VAL in raw ) return varchar2;
end;
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY          "PKG_LOGI_PWD_REG" 
as
  FUNCTION decrypt_val( p_val IN RAW ) RETURN VARCHAR2  
  IS
    l_decrypted RAW(32);
    l_decrypted_string VARCHAR2(32);
    L_USER  varchar2(32);
    L_CHARACTER_SET varchar2(10);
    L_STRING varchar2(32);
    L_KEY raw(250);
    L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
        L_KEY := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW
                            ( data => '98345678901234567890123456789012',
                              DST_CHARSET => 'AL32UTF8' );
        L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256 
                                        + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC 
                                        + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

        l_decrypted := dbms_crypto.decrypt
                ( SRC => P_VAL,
                  TYP => L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE,
                  key => L_KEY );

        l_decrypted_string := utl_i18n.raw_to_char
                    ( data => l_decrypted ,
                      src_charset => 'AL32UTF8' );
        RETURN l_decrypted_string;

  end DECRYPT_VAL;

  FUNCTION encrypt_val( p_val IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  is
    L_VAL RAW(32);
    L_ENCRYPTED raw(32);
    L_CHARACTER_SET varchar2(10);
    L_STRING varchar2(32);
    L_KEY RAW(250);
    L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE PLS_INTEGER;
  begin


    L_KEY := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW
                        ( data => '98345678901234567890123456789012',
                          DST_CHARSET => 'AL32UTF8' );
    L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256 
                                    + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC 
                                    + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
    L_VAL := utl_i18n.string_to_raw
              ( data => p_val,
                dst_charset => 'AL32UTF8' );

    L_ENCRYPTED := dbms_crypto.encrypt
                   ( SRC => L_VAL,
                     TYP => L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE,
                     key => L_KEY );


    return L_ENCRYPTED;
  EXCEPTION when OTHERS then
    RETURN SQLCODE||'-'||SQLERRM;
  end ENCRYPT_VAL;
end PKG_LOGI_PWD_REG;
/
```

Comment: could this be done with a CLOB as I am having issues getting my implementation working.   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69220222/oracle-incorrect-values-when-using-dbms-crypto-to-decrypt-a-clo

Comment: its working fine  for me thanks.