# Database agnostic database encrypt

Tags: java, encryption, jdbc, java-8

Is there a database agnostic way to encrypt passwords on the database in jdbc?
We are using java 8.

I know you can do it when you know which database you will be using, but as we support our customers using multiple platforms we need an agnostic way.

Edited Addition:
For example I know in mysql there are these string functions that can be used inside the sql statement. And presumed I had just not found the way to do it agnostically.

```
Name            Description
AES_DECRYPT()   Decrypt using AES
AES_ENCRYPT()   Encrypt using AES
DECODE()        Decodes a string encrypted using ENCODE()
DES_DECRYPT()   Decrypt a string
DES_ENCRYPT()   Encrypt a string
ENCODE()        Encode a string
```

Comment: Are you talking about a column with encrypted data inside?

Comment: yes, we want to store our passwords encrypted inside the table

Comment: [Never store encrypted passwords](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-12-15-never-store-passwords-in-a-database.html). Never!

Comment: You don't want to encrypt passwords, you want to hash them, and you should do that in your application, not in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hunting for examples for my edit i found this answer on a previous post and I agree with it.

> Of course, if you write your own routines, assuming that you store the
>   key in the database or somewhere the database has access to, you're
>   not doing much for security. It's bad to send passwords unencrypted
>   over the network but it is generally much worse to store unencrypted
>   passwords in the database (or encrypted passwords if there is a
>   decrypt method in the database that has access to the key to decrypt
>   the data). It's generally a lot easier to steal data from a database
>   than it is to sniff data getting sent over the network in order to
>   find a password.

[Encrypt/Decrypt Password in Oracle Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058356/encrypt-decrypt-password-in-oracle-function)

Answer (score 3):

Using industry standard best practices, you might want to store the salted hash of the password Base64 encoded or as a hex string in a normal varchar/text column. The encryption needs to be done on the Java side, but in the end it's nothing more than storing a String in the table. That should be database agnostic enough as it's a basic JDBC operation.