# Comparing Salt generated in Oracle Vs C#

Tags: c#, oracle, hash, plsql, sha512

We have a database table which contains passwords hashed with SHA512. When a user logs into the system it compares their hashed entered password with a hashed password stored in a table. I am trying to create a user through a PL/SQL script and I need to replicate the same process as the system does to create the user when it does it through the front end.

I'm having trouble clarifying if the salt I am generating for the hash in Oracle is what is generated by the system in C#. Since when I try to login and debug the system code, the hashed password generated by the system is not matching what I created through my PL/SQL script.

Currently, the system generates the hash with:

```
public string GetSalt(int count) // count = 32
{
    byte [] salt = new byte[count];
    using (var gen = new RNGCyptoServiceProvider()) // System.Security.Cryptography
    {
        gen.GetBytes(salt);
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
}
```

So we should get a cryptographically strong sequence of random values based on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2) for `GetBytes()`.

What I am doing in Oracle is the following:

```
FUNCTION GetSalt RETURN SomePasswordTable.Salt%TYPE IS
    defaultSaltLength   VARCHAR2(4);
    randomBytes RAW(1024);
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT SaltLength
        INTO defaultSaltLength -- This will be '32'
        FROM SomeTable
        WHERE someValue = 1
            AND someOtherValue = 'SALTLN';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            defaultSaltLength := '32';
    END;

    randomBytes := DBMS_CRYPTO.RandomBytes(TO_NUMBER(defaultSaltLength));

    RETURN utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(randomBytes));
END;
```

My question is, am I doing the same in Oracle as the system is doing in C#?

Based on the Oracle `DBMS_CRYPTO` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_crypto.htm#i1003214), `RandomBytes()` should also return me a cryptographically secure pseudo-random sequence of bytes.

Since both methods use the same hashing function. `DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH512` in Oracle and `PBKDF2HashAlgorithm.SHA512` in C#, this is the only place I can think of where the hashing is going wrong on the Oracle side.

Is what I am doing correct? Why am I getting a different hash?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994077/how-to-use-pbkdf2-in-oracle-12c

Comment: If the salt is random then 2 different salt byte sets are not supposed to match. If the salt is itself a hash of something like the user name, then it is derived and not random.  It is more common to save the salt with the PW hash and then use the same salt to test a password attempt.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow We are using the same salt in both hashing cases. That is, when you create a new user, it saves the salt. When a user logs in, the saved salt is used again. So the salt should remain the same when comparing. The method I included above is just the salt that the system does when it creates a new user. I wanted to replicate it in Oracle.